# Insert an array of zeros into hive

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table with a column of type array, how can I insert a record with say, an array of 1000 0s? I could just use a script to create an array of 1000 0s but looking for something more compact and less error prone

Answer (score 1):

Use `lpad` for generating string of `0` with length of 1000. then use `split` function to split result by empty string except beginning and end of the string:

```
hive> select split(lpad(0,1000,0),'(?!^)(?!$)');
```

**The result is an array of 1000 0s:**

```
["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack is to `select` 1000 rows from a table and then use `collect_list`.

```
select collect_list(res)
from (select 0 as res
      from tblWithGT1000Rows
      limit 1000
     ) t
```